# Confirm prompt using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm using powershell to automate a daily task. It is essentially a macro to refresh data linked to an external source and then sends an email out. The issue is that Excel automatically prompts for username/password whenever it tries to refresh the data. I did some digging and it can not be bypassed by setting DisplayAlert = False and cannot be changed from Excel's settings. My credentials are saved so what I really need to do is to have a script to press on "Enter".

I have the following set up currently: using Windows Scheduler, I first launch a Powershell script that'll open up Excel and run the macro to refresh the data. The macro will be stuck when Excel prompts for credentials. I have a second task which is scheduled to run 2 minutes after the first one and its purpose is to press on "Enter" to get rid of the prompt.

I have tried a couple of scripts for the second task but I just can't seem to get it right.
What I have tried is as follows:

```
[void]   [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate("Windows Security")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

and

```
$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

Any idea on how I can bypass/accept the prompt?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/277600) might help you. It tells you to edit the `.odc` file to be sure, that the password is saved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a solution slightly different from what you already tried. Maybe it is in the details...

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName
("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Windows Security")

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share the data link for more details, however, I would simply recreate the data link programmatically if indeed there is a reason why the pass & login can be saved e.g. a macro accepting pass and login

If it's a SQL connection then it would look something like this:

```
Sub Recreate(serverInstance as String, database as String, userId as String, password as String) 
    sConn = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & _
                    serverInstance & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & _
                    ";User ID=" & userId & ";Password=" & password & ";"

    Set qt = wks.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=sConn, _
                    Destination:=Target)
    With qt
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .CommandText = sql
            .Name = sName
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'Execute SQL
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The data link is from a third-party company. The excel file was created by them to pull data from their password-protected website.

Comment: What kind of data connection is this? We need more information. Right click on the data set to get more info.

Comment: It is a connection to their website that is username/password protected. Data connection string is similar to something like this:
https://www.website.com/viewserver/rw?port=BW_LE&client=clientname_gp&rpttag=iag_portvar_1y_bpsOwner=awjstjac&namedPreference=brs_var1&webQuery=true